# Does moneromooo have a direct donation address?

Tags: development-funding

I know there's a general Monero project donation address [here](https://getmonero.org/get-started/contributing/).

I'm not sure if that only goes to the core team.  moneromoo is not listed as a core team member [here](https://getmonero.org/community/team/), but he has the most commits shown [here](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/graphs/contributors).

Also, I know he gets paid sometimes with the FFS like [here](https://forum.getmonero.org/9/work-in-progress/87789/mooo-full-time-july-september), but I'd like to know where someone can send a one off donation.

Others have expressed interest in donating directly to him like [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/6nhpj5/what_is_the_most_popular_technical_resource_on/dk9m3xf/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

His donation addresses are:

`Monero: 4AfUP827TeRZ1cck3tZThgZbRCEwBrpcJTkA1LCiyFVuMH4b5y59bKMZHGb9y58K3gSjWDCBsB4RkGsGDhsmMG5R2qmbLeW`

`Aeon: WmtXcFZj5iGY21JxAtFsJVQmQQyo7jgoJP8V4zLWVzDeeTfvbP8Mzb5gbNpQEc6BkeUYUqjGntHDSDyA6LKjdGBQ1w9iEpfVw`, as seen in his [address generator](https://github.com/moneromooo-monero/monero-wallet-generator/blob/master/monero-wallet-generator.html) page.

Comment: Isn't that a Monero testnet address?

Comment: fixed, was missing the 1st char